# occasional long (500+ ms) Write or Flush times in golang

Tags: file, go, io, flush, goroutine

I have project where we read data from some source, process it, then write some subset and possibly compressed version of that data to disk. We write in many (usually around 200) different files to correspond to different "channels" of the data, and often write a few MB/s to disc across these files.

I'm seeing that approximately once every minute or so, a call to `Write` or to `Flush` takes a around 500 ms. I'd to reduce that number down to below 50 ms if possible.

I tried to make a minimum working example (MWE) with this odd behvior, but I can't reproduce the long  `Write` and `Flush` calls on the machine that has that behavior with our full project. However, on my MacBook Pro laptop, I can cause 50 ms `Flush` calls which is still 100 times longer than typical. The attempted MWE is below, and it reproduces to way we're writing data nearly exactly. It has some flags at the top for flushing in different parts of the code, I was testing to see if calling `Flush` in certain locations helped. Any guidance on how to get consistent timings on the `Flush` and `Write` calls would be super helpful. Even if the average write time was slower, I just want consistent behavior.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

const flushWithinBlock = true
const flushAfterBlocks = true

type Writer struct {
    FileName      string
    headerWritten bool
    writer        *bufio.Writer
}

func (w *Writer) writeHeader() error {
    file, err := os.Create(w.FileName)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    w.writer = bufio.NewWriterSize(file, 32768)
    w.writer.WriteString("HEADER\n")
    w.headerWritten = true
    return nil
}

func (w *Writer) writeRecord(nBytes int) error {
    data := make([]byte, nBytes)
    nWritten, err := w.writer.Write(data)
    if nWritten != nBytes {
        return fmt.Errorf("wrong number of bytes written")
    }
    return err
}

func main() {
    dirname, err0 := ioutil.TempDir("", "")
    if err0 != nil {
        panic(err0)
    }
    fmt.Println(dirname)
    recordLength := 500
    numberOfChannels := 240
    recordsPerChanPerTick := 5
    writers := make([]*Writer, numberOfChannels)
    abortChan := make(chan struct{})
    for i := range writers {
        writers[i] = &Writer{FileName: fmt.Sprintf("%v/%v.ljh", dirname, i)}
    }
    go func() {
        signalChan := make(chan os.Signal)
        signal.Notify(signalChan, os.Interrupt)
        <-signalChan
        close(abortChan)
    }()

    tickDuration := 50 * time.Millisecond
    ticker := time.NewTicker(tickDuration)
    z := 0
    tLast := time.Now()
    fmt.Printf("recordsPerChanPerTick %v, Chans %v, tickDuration %v\n", recordsPerChanPerTick, numberOfChannels, tickDuration)
    fmt.Printf("records/second/chan %v, records/second total %v\n", float64(recordsPerChanPerTick)/tickDuration.Seconds(), float64(recordsPerChanPerTick*numberOfChannels)/tickDuration.Seconds())
    fmt.Printf("megabytes/second total %v\n", float64(recordLength)*float64(recordsPerChanPerTick*numberOfChannels)/tickDuration.Seconds()*1e-6)
    fmt.Printf("flushWithinBlock %v, flushAfterBlocks %v\n", flushWithinBlock, flushAfterBlocks)
    for {
        // 1. here we would get data from data source
        z++
        select {
        case <-abortChan:
            fmt.Println("clean exit")
            return
        case <-ticker.C:
            var wg sync.WaitGroup
            writeDurations := make([]time.Duration, numberOfChannels)
            flushDurations := make([]time.Duration, numberOfChannels)
            for i, w := range writers {
                wg.Add(1)
                go func(w *Writer, i int) {
                    tStart := time.Now()

                    defer wg.Done()
                    for j := 0; j < recordsPerChanPerTick; j++ {
                        if !w.headerWritten {
                            err := w.writeHeader()
                            if err != nil {
                                panic(fmt.Sprintf("failed create file and write header: %v\n", err))
                            }
                        }
                        w.writeRecord(recordLength)
                    }
                    tWrite := time.Now()
                    if flushWithinBlock {
                        w.writer.Flush()
                    }
                    writeDurations[i] = tWrite.Sub(tStart)
                    flushDurations[i] = time.Now().Sub(tWrite)
                }(w, i)
            }
            wg.Wait()
            for _, w := range writers {
                if flushAfterBlocks {
                    w.writer.Flush()
                }
            }
            var writeSum time.Duration
            var flushSum time.Duration
            var writeMax time.Duration
            var flushMax time.Duration
            for i := range writeDurations {
                writeSum += writeDurations[i]
                flushSum += flushDurations[i]
                if writeDurations[i] > writeMax {
                    writeMax = writeDurations[i]
                }
                if flushDurations[i] > flushMax {
                    flushMax = flushDurations[i]
                }
            }
            if z%100 == 0 || time.Now().Sub(tLast) > 75*time.Millisecond {
                fmt.Printf("z %v, time.Now().Sub(tLast) %v\n", z, time.Now().Sub(tLast))
                fmt.Printf("writeMean %v, flushMean %v, writeMax %v, flushMax %v\n", writeSum/time.Duration(numberOfChannels), flushSum/time.Duration(numberOfChannels), writeMax, flushMax)
            }
            tLast = time.Now()
        }
    }

}
```

Example output on a Ubuntu 16 machine with a spinning hard drive, this is the actual hardware that has 500 ms `Write` and `Flush` calls in our full project:

```
/tmp/296105809
recordsPerChanPerTick 5, Chans 240, tickDuration 50ms
records/second/chan 100, records/second total 24000
megabytes/second total 12
flushWithinBlock true, flushAfterBlocks true
z 1, time.Now().Sub(tLast) 75.96973ms
writeMean 14.017745ms, flushMean 7.847µs, writeMax 24.761147ms, flushMax 420.896µs
z 100, time.Now().Sub(tLast) 50.13856ms
writeMean 1.71µs, flushMean 4.213µs, writeMax 12.271µs, flushMax 32.133µs
z 200, time.Now().Sub(tLast) 50.006063ms
writeMean 1.651µs, flushMean 3.032µs, writeMax 79.006µs, flushMax 7.246µs
z 300, time.Now().Sub(tLast) 50.151421ms
writeMean 1.685µs, flushMean 4.542µs, writeMax 10.429µs, flushMax 14.087µs
z 400, time.Now().Sub(tLast) 50.059208ms
```

Example output on a MacBook Pro with an SSD. You can see some much longer `Write` and `Flush` calls here, but nothing in the 500 ms range. Note the 30 ms `flushMax` on line 81 vs more typical 500 us `flushMax` on line 100.

```
/var/folders/_0/25kp6h7x25v6vyjv2yjlcnkm000wrm/T/934618054
recordsPerChanPerTick 5, Chans 240, tickDuration 50ms
records/second/chan 100, records/second total 24000
megabytes/second total 12
flushWithinBlock true, flushAfterBlocks true
z 1, time.Now().Sub(tLast) 84.897446ms
writeMean 10.265068ms, flushMean 464.53µs, writeMax 24.752873ms, flushMax 3.528286ms
... some output removed
... NOTE, line 81 was printed because it took longer than normal
z 81, time.Now().Sub(tLast) 75.804358ms
writeMean 15.056µs, flushMean 18.324892ms, writeMax 408.406µs, flushMax 30.765425ms
z 100, time.Now().Sub(tLast) 54.753448ms
writeMean 3.25µs, flushMean 84.963µs, writeMax 74.152µs, flushMax 499.322µs
```

Comment: I'm not sure where the exact solution lies between Go and the operating system,  but if you watch a graph of disk I/O when you run this, you'll notice (at least on my Mac with SSD) very little activity, but the graph will spike and the Go test will spit out a bunch of high latency write times. Somewhere along the pipeline from memory to disk, you need to reduce the write buffer size (which may be a bad idea depending on specific application). As to exactly where, I'm not sure, but it's very possibly in the OS, or disk level. Graph spike: https://imgur.com/a/ATNGSKE

Comment: ok two comments 1) the fact that you can't produce a MWE shows that it is probably the OS or other programs causing issues 2) if you launch a go routine to do the update what does it matter how long it takes?  nothing is blocked :)

Comment: @Vorsprung, the way it's written now, I do wait on the file writing since the goroutines are mainly for parallelism of processing. If I cant figure out how to resolve the occasional slow `Write` then I'll re-write it to shuttle put all the data to be written on a channel and have a file writing routine.

Comment: @Vorsprung, the way it's written now, I do wait on the file writing since the goroutines primarily to avoid race conditions related to changing what data is written. I'm thinking about how to restructure it to 1. not wait on write 2. avoid race conditions when write settings change 3. guarantee in order writing while still processing data every 50 ms.